# Shared memory arithmetic operation instruction level parallelism

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

In Kepler, to obtain ILP, should we separate arithmetic operations where the operands are from shared memory?  I don't know if it (arithmetic operation where the operand is shared memory) is separated into two operations, one is loading from shared memory to a register and then do operation on the register or if it is one operation.

Because in the book "Programming Massively Parallel Multiprocessors" part 6 on data prefetching says that loading into shared memory consists of two parts (first from global memory to register and then register to shared memory).

E.g. will this statement produce ILP?

```
result1=opA[1]+opB[1]; // opA and opB in Shared mem, result1 in register
result2=opC[1]+opD[1];// opC and opD in Shared mem, result2 in register
```

or should we break down like this to make ILP?

```
temp1=opA[1]; temp2=opB[1];
temp3=opC[1];temp4=opD[1];//temp variable in register
result1=temp1+temp2;
result2=temp3+temp4;
```

Comment: The compiler understands what is needed and will probably do a better job than you can of these local rearrangements to achieve best ILP.

Comment: yes, you are right, breaking the instruction give worse result.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you are unlikely to see improvements because the compiler will probably handle this case better (as Robert Crovella said in his comment).

There are situations where prefetching in this fashion could potentially help hide some latency, though.  If you were to use a vector type to combine multiple fetches into a single fetch, thereby better utilizing the bus, you may be able to see an improvement.

A very simple example:

```
float4 temp1 = A[0];
float4 temp2 = A[1];

result1 = temp1.x + temp1.y + temp1.z + temp1.w;
num = result1 * 3.14159;
result2 = temp2.x * num + temp2.y * num + temp2.z + temp2.w * num;
```

This would result in the calculations for `result1` and `num` being able to take place while the fetch for `temp2` is happening, thereby helping to hide some of that fetch latency.

This really isn't a very good example, but hopefully you get the general idea.  One situation where prefetching is a bit better suited for is when you are doing something in a loop. If you prefetch the first set of data you need for the first iteration of the loop, the contents of the loop can execute while fetching data for the next iteration, and so forth.

A simple example of this:

```
float4 temp = A[0];
float sum = 0;
for( int i = 4; i < sizeA - 4; i+=4 ) {
    sum = temp.x + temp.y + temp.z + temp.w;
    temp = A[i];
}
```